# How to expand a div width to show more content in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i am trying to basically add a expand button to my react app that will reveal more information and i would prefer that the app expand the div size to make the additional content fit i understand i need to utilize the usestate property and a function however i am having a hard time figuring out how do i update the css of the student div to expand and reveal the added information. The added information is the grades portion (FYI). Some help would be greatly appreciated.

My App.js code so far

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState(null);
  const [filterData, setFilterData ] = useState(null);

  const studentdata = 'https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students';

  function getStudents(){
    fetch(studentdata)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        setFilterData(data.students);
        setStudents(data.students);
      })
  }

  const searchByName = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    // Get the search term
    const searchItem = event.target.value.toLowerCase().trim();
    // If search term is empty fill with full students data
    if(!searchItem.trim()) {
      setFilterData(students);
    }
    // Search the name and if it found retun the same array
    const serachIn = (firstName, lastName) => {
      if(firstName.indexOf(searchItem) !== -1 || lastName.indexOf(searchItem) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
      let fullName = firstName.toLowerCase()+" "+lastName.toLowerCase();
      if(fullName.indexOf(searchItem) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };
    // Filter the array 
    const filteredData = students.filter((item) => {
      return serachIn(item.firstName, item.lastName);
    });
    // Set the state with filtered data
    setFilterData(filteredData);
  }

   return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Students</h1>

      <div>
        <button className="fetch-button" onClick={getStudents}>
          Get Students
        </button>
        <br />
      </div>

      <div className="search" id="search">
          <input type="text" name="serachByName" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search by name" onChange={(e) => searchByName(e)} ></input>
      </div>

      {filterData && filterData.map((student, index) => {
       var total = 0;
       for(var i = 0; i < student.grades.length; i++) {
        var grade = parseInt(student.grades[i]);
        total += grade;
       }
       const avg = total / student.grades.length;
       const average = avg.toString();
       const grade1 = student.grades[0];
       const grade2 = student.grades[1];
       const grade3 = student.grades[2];
       const grade4 = student.grades[3];
       const grade5 = student.grades[4];
       const grade6 = student.grades[5];
       const grade7 = student.grades[6];
       const grade8 = student.grades[7];

      return(
      <div className="student" key={index}>
        <div className="image">
          <img src={student.pic} id="icon"></img>
        </div>

        <div className="text">
          <h3 id="name">{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</h3>
          <p id="detail"><strong>EMAIL:</strong> {student.email}</p>
          <p id="detail"><strong>COMPANY:</strong> {student.company}</p>
          <p id="detail"><strong>SKILL:</strong> {student.skill}</p>
          <p id="detail"><strong>AVERAGE:</strong>: {average}%</p>
          <p id="detail"><strong>GRADES:</strong>:<br></br>
            <br></br>Test 1 :{grade1}  
            <br></br>Test 2 :{grade2}
            <br></br>Test 3 :{grade3}  
            <br></br>Test 4 :{grade4}
            <br></br>Test 5 :{grade5}  
            <br></br>Test 6 :{grade6}
            <br></br>Test 7 :{grade7}  
            <br></br>Test 8 :{grade8}
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className="expand">
          <button className="expand_btn" id="expand_btn">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      )}
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the css i am using

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400&display=swap');

.root{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}



.App {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.student{
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.text{
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 7%;
  width: 300px;
}

.image{
  padding-left: 15%;
}

#icon{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#name{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#detail {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.search {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#searchbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


.expand {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#expand_btn {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: lightskyblue;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get for an expanded state and then add on the className to that to apply the styling. Try something like this

```
const expand = () =>{
  setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
}
```

```
 <div className={'student' + isExpanded ? 'expand' : '' }key={index}>

 </div>
 <button className="expand_btn" onClick={expand()} id="expand_btn">+</button>
```

Comment: so how would i go about defining isExpanded so i would need const [expand, isExpanded] = useState(false); then i need to define the isExpanded function but how would i go about doing that???

Comment: ive updated my answer to include an example on adding an onclick listener

Comment: so i tried that but i am getting errors still the error i am getting is Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. i am not sure if this line is correct i wrote it as const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false); and i changed the function name to exp()

Comment: if you know how to prevent the above error that would be great because i am not sure how to overcome this